# Don't Show Usernames at Boot

Tags: windows-10, boot, user-accounts, login-screen

I'm trying to prevent Windows 10 Pro (1903) from displaying usernames on the initial login screen on system boot-up. I've tried everything listed in the accepted answer [here on Microsoft TechNet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2ab569f5-ec46-4f54-a544-42504589d920/windows-10-logon-screen-retain-previously-logged-domain-users?forum=win10itprosetup), but that only seems to prevent the last login user from being displayed ***after you log out***.  It does not appear to work at all for hiding username(s) ***on system boot-up***.

I've looked all over and played with any setting that looks even remotely right; no luck.  How can I prevent Windows 10 from ***ever*** displaying the username (there's only one) on the login screen, including when the machine is first booted?

Comment: Personally, I do that by configuring the following within the Local Group Policy Editor:  navigate to `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options` and **Disable** the policy for *Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL*

Comment: Did that.  When I CTRL+ALT+DEL, it takes me to the username already used, directly to the password entry...  but I don't want the username there at ***all.*** I want it to have to be typed.

Comment: And you also enabled *Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in*?

Comment: Yep, sure did...

Comment: Well, that doesn't entirely make sense.  The Windows 10 Pro machines on my home workgroup are already configured to do *exactly* what you want, and that's how I made it happen.  It sounds like you have some other Group Policy or Registry setting that might be overriding what I have configured, because it works perfectly.

Comment: Ah-HA, setting **Interactive Logon: Number of previous logons to cache...** to **0** seems to do the trick.

Comment: Perhaps, but mine is still set to the default (10) and it already works.  I think it's simply a matter of *so* many changes that may have been conflicting with one another.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that (too many cooks spoiling the broth etc.), and tried only doing one GP setting at a time... but it still wouldn't prevent the username from being displayed at least on reboot and startup.

Comment: Understood but as I said before, mine works perfectly (and has been for over four years) based upon just those two Group Policy settings:  enabled [Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-do-not-display-last-user-name) as well as disabled [Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/interactive-logon-do-not-require-ctrl-alt-del)

Comment: We use Active Directory and haven't needed to do anything other than the two GPOs that Run5k mentions. All affected systems boot to a blank username/password prompt. @DavidMancini: Are you configuring standalone systems (non-AD workstations) here?

Comment: @grawity - Yes, just a vanilla Windows 10 Pro (clean install), latest updates, no AD / Domain.

Comment: As I said before, although you had the best of intentions, your extensive changes must have adversely affected those machines.  I have implemented this on hundreds of Windows 10 Pro builds over the past four years, and I have never seen those two Group Policies *not* work on a cleanly installed OS.

Comment: Once again, it may be prudent for you to simply delete this question. We can't really submit an answer that would typically help the vast majority of community members, since it didn't work for *you* under your rather extraordinary circumstances.